# create snapshot of compute instance group in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snapshot

I have the following setup in google cloud.

1. Http load balancer will balance between 2 instance groups in different regions
2. Each instance group have minimum of 2 instances and maximum of 5 instances

I want to schedule a snapshot for each running instances at any moment. Since i don't know upfront how many instances will be running at any moment, what is the better way to create snapshot of every running instances. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

My main question is about what are you trying to save. If you are running MIGs (Managed Instance Groups) all of your VMs are clones of the Instance Template. Maybe another approach is better here. If you are trying to save logs, send your logs to [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs) ; if you are trying to preserve objects, send your files to a Storage Bucket or use [Cloud Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs). So, what are you trying to preserve? Maybe Snapshots are no the best solution for your case